# Performance issue with new dual boot Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, uefi, performance

I have installed ubuntu next to windows on my laptop, I followed all the steps and I took all preventions reagarding to the installation, but once the installation is completed, it turns out that the OS performance is really really bad (every action in the PC is terribly slow). It takes about 2 minutes just to start (from the beginning to the log-in screen). I attach more information about the PC and the OS versions I have tried.

PC details:

- MANUFACTURER: ASUS (ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.)
- MODEL: [ASUS TUF Gaming F15 FX506LI_FX506LI](https://www.asus.com/es/Laptops/For-Gaming/TUF-Gaming/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-F15/)
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2496 Mhz
- MAIN OS: WINDOWS 10 (Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language)
- BIOS MODEL: UEFI
- RAM MEMORY: 8GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 ti

I have tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Ubuntu 21.04, and I don't really know why the performance of the OS is so bad, I mean, in relation to the hardware it should run really well.

I really thank all of you guys in advance for your help!

Comment: That system looks new enough that you probably need 21.04 for latest kernel & drivers. Otherwise we typically recommend LTS versions, so you do not have to update to newer version as often. Did you choose to install restricted drivers, to get correct nVidia driver installed by default? Do not install a new nVidia driver without totally purging old driver or conflicts create even more issues, new driver does not delete old. ASUS TUF GAMING FX506L - Install nVidia driver
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2460560 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers